# smach_ros.MonitorState callback receives empty userdata

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For our AMIGO robot, I'm building a very simple state machine in smach for asking questions and asking for confirmation of the answers.

After posing the question via text-to-speech, the statemachine waits for the answer from speech-to-text with a MonitorState called WAIT_ANSWER. The callback for the MonitorState simply checks if there are any options given (Yes, the robot reads mentions them when asking the question), and then if the answer given is one of the options.

Sounds simple, but somehow the userdata in the callback only contains an empty instance of smach.Remapper.
The msg-parameter of the callback does get the correct value.

When running, the state machine containing the state *does* have the userdata 'question_senstence' and 'options'. In Smach Viewer, it also looks fine.

The fact that there are no tutorials on MonitorState doesn't help, so my implementation is based on my interpretation of the source code.

Does anyone have any experience with MonitorStates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28100/smach_ros.monitorstate-callback-receives-empty-userdata/) by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had the same problem. I use MonitorState in a Concurrence container and want to store some data in userdata.

To get it working i had to do the following:

In file [monitor_state.py](https://github.com/ros/executive_smach/blob/hydro-devel/smach_ros/src/smach_ros/monitor_state.py) i changed line 29 from

```
self._sub = rospy.Subscriber(self._topic, self._msg_type, self._cb, callback_args=[ud])
```

to

```
self._sub = rospy.Subscriber(self._topic, self._msg_type, self._cb, callback_args=ud)
```

and overloaded the `smach_ros.MonitorState.__init__` function to accept my desired input and output keys.

```
class MonitorState2(smach_ros.MonitorState):
    def __init__(self, topic, msg_type, cond_cb, max_checks=-1):
    smach.State.__init__(self,
            outcomes=['nav_error', 'pose_reached'],
            input_keys=['user_pose'],
            output_keys=['user_pose', 'robot_current_pose'])

    self._topic = topic 
    self._msg_type = msg_type 
    self._cond_cb = cond_cb 
    self._max_checks = max_checks 
    self._n_checks = 0 

    self._trigger_cond = threading.Condition()
```

---

Originally posted by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) with karma: 206 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-06-18**:
I know it's an old thread but could you explain to me why you have to change the [ud] of the Subscriber and why it is not like this in the original implementation ? Thanks.

**Comment by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on 2014-06-22**:
Otherwise the userdata would not have passed to the next state. Nowadays I use the WaitForMsgState to retrieve data from a topic. You can find it on this page http://wiki.ros.org/executive_smach/AdditionalStateTypes

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2015-03-15**:
Yeah so apparently callback_args in rospy.Subscriber isn't an array of arguments, but just the single additional argument passed to subscriber callbacks. I.e. this is the correct usage: https://gist.github.com/jbohren/085c529c9063aed64386

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2015-03-15**:
Fixed in https://github.com/ros/executive_smach/commit/1a158b177430dd1e52b64e0157c8af65a0f318b8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@phil0stine asked a [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/30492/smach-sub-state-machine-userdata/) whose answer may help you out.

Also, I just updated the [MonitorState](http://ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/MonitorState) documentation with an example, in case that helps.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1